# why the output of the following program different (random value) every time?

Tags: c

Can we assign the string value to the int variable? what conversion is happening at line int a="aa";
  I am running this C program and the value is printing different for each program execution.

```
 int main() 
{
   int a="aa";
   printf("%d",++a);
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

In C, the string literal `"aa"` is a `char *` (in C++ a `const char *`) to a read-only memory location of the string `"aa"`. You are converting this pointer to an integer, i.e. you are converting the memory address to a number. Depending on the platform you are using, this memory address may change every time your program runs.

Comment: Not `const char *`, merely `char *`. It is UB to attempt to modify the contents of a string literal, but they are not `const`.

Comment: @exnihilo: In my Microsoft C++ compiler, the type is `const char *`. Is there maybe a difference between C and C++ in this respect?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel In C++ string literals are `const char*`, in C they are merely `char *`

Comment: @nickelpro: Thanks, I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel -- FYI, [here is the relevant passage](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6) from the C Standard.